# Kbmmw. Can't activate Logout Event on kbmMWAuthorizationManager

Tags: delphi

I'm testing Autorization (client\server) sample from kbmmw (Delphi 8.1).

When I run kbmMWSimpleClient1.Connect on the client side I get onLogin event on the server side.

When I run kbmMWSimpleClient1.Disconnect on the client side I can't get onLogout event on kbmMWAuthorizationManager object.

How to activate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the login event on the initial connection, because you have defined that the client should auto login on first request (mwaoAutoLogin).

However a disconnection do not automatically mean that the client is logged out. It can be a temporary disconnection, or it could be a planned disconnection, if the client is a browser that is configured to connect, POST/GET and disconnect on each request.
So diconnection <> logout, in the same sense that connection <> login. First request = login if mwaoAutoLogin is defined.

There are two ways to logout security wise.

1. Explicitely by calling Logout method, for example because the user on
   the client clicks a logout button.
2. Implicitely by the login times out due to idle time. If no request is being 
   made via that particular login token for a specified amount of time, the
   authorization manager will automatically ensure a logout for the
   token is happening.

The property DefaultMaxIdleTime on the authorization mananger defines the default idle time before autologout. Its currently 3600 seconds = 1 hour.
Its also possible to have different default values for different actors by setting the actors MaxIdleTime property when the actors are defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an expanded reply. Could I ask more question about timeout. I started server and two clients (authorization demo). All requests ("query all" btn) fulfilled but after a few minutes I pressed "query all" bottom and received en error "Anonymous user not authorized".

Comment: Disconnect and reConnect function doesn't help and I can't restart query without restarting a program. How to solve it?

Comment: Anonymous requests typically means that it does not find a username/password nor a token in the clients request. Remember the Token you get on your first request should be reused for all subsequent requests by all client code (all kbmMWSimpleClient, kbmMWClientQuery, kbmMWClientResolver etc). On way to centralize that is to put a TkbmMWSimpleClient on the datamodule and specify all the client query components to use this simple client instance as a template. Then as the first thing before anything else in your client application, make an initial "login" request call  via the simpleclient.